# An unknown error when programing with bcm2835 (i2c)

Tags: i2c, c

Forgive my broken english.

I am using a RaspberryPI 3b+.
I have written a program using the bcm2835 C library and I have found that none of my code worked. Even printf(). (there is no error when I build my .c file or run in root)
Later I test with code.

```
    printf("1");
    bcm2835_delay(2000);
    bcm2835_i2c_setSlaveAddress(0x5C);
    printf("1");
    bcm2835_delay(2000);
```

The result was there was only a 2 second pause(no print) and then program ended.

I am very confused. What problem is it and how to solve it?

I also found in "lsmod" there have "spi_bcm2835""bcm2835_gpiomem/rng""i2c_bcm2708""snd_bcm2835"so on. Don't know wether can help.

Anyway, I will appreciate anyone who could provide me help.

Answer (score 0):

printf output is line buffered by default, i.e. the line is output when a new line is detected.

Use, for example, `printf("1\n");` to add a new line to your output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try compiling with a debug flag,run the program and gdb into it. What happens before the first printf?

Vittal

Comment: Thanks for advice.The program print "1" and pause for 2s.Then crash down with information   " Program received signal SIGSEGV ,Segmentation fault.    bcm2835_peri_write(paddr=0xb,value=92) at bcm 2835.c:1600                      160                 *paddr = value;   "

Comment: Well..... Maybe I solve this problem myself.There may need  a"bcm2835_init();" and "bcm2835_i2c_begin();"before all ..........It may caused by some of mine misunderstanding.....Anyway thanks.